# Trigger Submit Event when Widget is added to Sidebar

Tags: widgets, jquery

I need to trigger the submit or "Save" button for a widget when the widget is added to a specific sidebar in the backend. The reason for this is I am setting a certain taxonomy for a Dropdown Menu inside each widget. The code for setting the taxonomy works fine as long as after adding a widget you hit the "Save" button or refresh the page after the widget has been added.

Here is my code inside jQuery I am using to capture the Ajax event when a widget gets added to a sidebar and to trigger the submit button to force a Save action.

```
$( document ).ajaxStop( function() {
    var $saveBtns = $('#products_sidebar').find('input[submit]').trigger('submit');
} );
```

I am capturing the Ajax event correctly and able to console out the contents of the sidebar:

```
console.log("sidebar: " + $('#products_sidebar').html() );
```

However the submit action is not getting triggered.

thanks

Comment: Likely duplicate: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/130084/executing-javascript-when-a-widget-is-added-in-the-backend?rq=1

Comment: If you think the question is a duplicate, please delete it. If not, please post your **EDIT** as an *answer* below and then accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Based off [the example @mrwweb provided above](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/130084/executing-javascript-when-a-widget-is-added-in-the-backend?rq=1) and some additional code, here is an answer that works. This answer forces a widget to save when a widget is added to a sidebar. It finds all the "Save" buttons and triggers their click event thus saving the widget. The count variable is used to stop an endless loop from occurring.

```
var count = 0;
$( document ).ajaxStop( function() {
    var $saveBtns = $('#products_sidebar, #blog_sidebar').find('.widget-control-save');
    if (count < $saveBtns.length) {
        $saveBtns.each( function( index, value ){
            $(value).trigger('click');
            count++;
        });
    }
    else {
        count = 0;
        return;
    }

} );
```